# Error while viewing a pdf file using latex-suite in macVim

Tags: vim, latex, macvim, latex-suite

I get this error after typing lv for viewing the pdf file in macVim. 
Note: after compiling it (with ll) without any problem:

Error detected while processing function Tex_ViewLaTeX:
line   34:
E121: Undefined variable: s:viewer
E116: Invalid arguments for function strlen(s:viewer)
E15: Invalid expression: strlen(s:viewer)
line   39:
E121: Undefined variable: appOpt
E15: Invalid expression: 'open '.appOpt.s:viewer.' $*.'.s:target
line   79:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E116: Invalid arguments for function substitute(execString, '\V$*', mainfname, 'g
')
E15: Invalid expression: substitute(execString, '\V$*', mainfname, 'g')
line   80:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E116: Invalid arguments for function Tex_Debug
line   82:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E15: Invalid expression: 'silent! !'.execString

I already defined the pdf viewer in the .vimrc file with 
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'open -a Preview'

Also tried treating macUnix as Unix with
let g:Tex_TreatMacViewerAsUNIX = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://www.tedpavlic.com/research_related/tpavlic_masters_thesis/compiler.vim), it seems that the `lv` function launches the dvi viewer, *not* the pdf-viewer.

If you want to preview a dvi file, you should have [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) installed, and then you can define

```
let g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi = 'open -a xdvi'
```

If you want to preview a pdf file with MacVim, you should define a new viewer command altogether, which I don't think can be done without changing the [source code](http://www.tedpavlic.com/research_related/tpavlic_masters_thesis/compiler.vim).

Comment: The dvi file is converted to pdf, apparently only reopening macvim with let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'open -a Preview.app' is enough. The changes I made in mi vimrc file are not refreshed in Macvim (unlike in vim on the terminal) so I was still working with the older configuration of the vimrc file. Very naive indeed. Nevertheless thank you for the answer.